# How to Redirect to login page in Keycloak and Apache Deltaspike?

Tags: security, jsf, jakarta-ee, keycloak, deltaspike

I am working on a Java EE web application that will leverage [Keycloak](https://keycloak.org) as an identity and authentication provider.  Further, I am using [Apache DeltaSpike](http://deltaspike.apache.org) within the project for various purposes.  I would like to leverage DeltaSpike's [security module](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/security.html) to allow me to annotate methods indicating that a user must be logged in to access them.  If this check fails, I would like to redirect the user to the Keycloak login page automatically.  However, I have yet to figure out a way to accomplish this.

The relevant y web.xml file looks like this, showing that I've configured Keycloak as the security mechanism for my app:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
    <realm-name>KEYCLOAK</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

I've implemented a corresponding `AccessDecisionVoter` that looks like this:

```
public class LoginRequiredAccessDecisionVoter extends AbstractAccessDecisionVoter {

    @Inject
    private KeycloakSecurityContext securityContext = null;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see
     * org.apache.deltaspike.security.api.authorization.AbstractAccessDecisionVoter#
     * checkPermission(org.apache.deltaspike.security.api.authorization.
     * AccessDecisionVoterContext, java.util.Set)
     */
    @Override
    protected void checkPermission(AccessDecisionVoterContext accessDecisionVoterContext,
            Set<SecurityViolation> violations) {
        if (securityContext == null) {
            violations.add(new LoginRequiredSecurityViolation());
        }
    }

}
```

Then, I configured DeltaSpike's [type-aware JSF navigation](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jsf.html#Type-safeView-Configs) to be secured using this class.  I hit a secured resource with my browser and see that my `AccessDecisionVoter` is triggered.  I see the `checkPermission` method being called and an `ErrorViewAwareAccessDeniedException` being thrown.  So, I implemented an `ExceptionHandler` to catch the exception and redirect the user to the Keycloak login page.  It looks like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler
public class SecurityExceptionHandler {

    @Inject
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest = null;

    @Inject
    @DeltaSpike
    private HttpServletResponse servletResponse = null;

    /**
     * Handles {@link ErrorViewAwareAccessDeniedException} exceptions
     * 
     * @param event The exception event
     */
    public void handleErrorViewAwareAccessDeniedException(
            @Handles ExceptionEvent<ErrorViewAwareAccessDeniedException> event) {
        Set<SecurityViolation> violations = event.getException().getViolations();
        for (SecurityViolation v : violations) {
            if (v instanceof LoginRequiredSecurityViolation) {
                try {
                    this.servletRequest.authenticate(this.servletResponse);
                    event.handled();
                } catch (IOException | ServletException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My thought is that the `servletRequest.authenticate()` call will kickoff the redirect to the Keycloak login page.  However, that is not the case.  Instead, I get a `ServletException`/`NullPointerException` thrown.

Is there a better way to redirect the user to Keycloak programmatically? Is there an exception or something that can be thrown to trigger the redirect?  Thoughts?

**UPDATE:**  Here is the Exception I am receiving:

```
11:17:54,256 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /tests/loginTest.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:725)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.event.EventBridgeFilter.doFilter(EventBridgeFilter.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.produce.RequestResponseHolderFilter.doFilter(RequestResponseHolderFilter.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.elytron.KeycloakServletExtension.lambda$null$0(KeycloakServletExtension.java:39)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getRequestDispatcher(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:957)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:692)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.dispatch(ExternalContextWrapper.java:91)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:356)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.render(DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.java:111)
    at javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleWrapper.render(LifecycleWrapper.java:88)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.JsfClientWindowAwareLifecycleWrapper.render(JsfClientWindowAwareLifecycleWrapper.java:160)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: What does the NullPointerException stacktrace look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!  All it required was to call `FacesContext#responseComplete()` prior to the `authenticate` call.  So, the relevant section of code now looks like this (also cleaned up a bit):

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) ctx.getExternalContext().getRequest();
HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse();

ctx.responseComplete();
req.authenticate(resp);

event.handled();
```